# Click on button to open a new form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, text-based

I'm trying to create a text-based game where the user selects buttons and that will lead to other parts of the game, right now I need the program to close the old Form and the new form must be placed in where the old one was.

Comment: you'll only get extremely limited help unless you provide more details and CODE YOU'VE TRIED. http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets13p3.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
Dim form2 As New Form2
'set start position to manual
form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
'set form2 location the same as current form
form2.DesktopLocation = Me.DesktopLocation
form2.Show()
Me.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
me.close()

Dim SecondForm As New frmSecond

SecondForm.Show()
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution?

Comment: me.close - close the current form and frm second form is a second form that can be show